# How to return value from method in another component?

Tags: angular

I have component details.ts where i have this method:

```
getCantonsByCode(cantonCode: string) {    
    this.restService.getSelectedByCode("rcanton", cantonCode)
    .subscribe(results => {
        return this.canton = results["payload"];
    });
 }
```

In component address.ts i want to do something like this:

```
   this.addressDetailForm.addressDetails.viewAttr2 = this.addressDetailForm.getCantonsByCode(address.cantonCode)
```

But im getting undefined. Any suggestion how can i return that value ?

Answer (score 1):

Address component should access data directly through service just like details component does. In general, components should not be aware of each other especially not for accessing data.
It makes no sense to access data (service layer) through other component (UI layer).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do, is to change your code to the following:

```
getCantonsByCode(cantonCode: string) {    
    this.restService.getSelectedByCode("rcanton", cantonCode)
        .subscribe(results => {
        this.canton = results["payload"];
        return this.canton;
    });
}
```

However, if this doesn't fix your problem, you should make sure if `results` is really what you expect.

**Edit**

I agree with the other answer, that you should not access the data via attribute of the service, so I will refine my answer. You should do the following:

```
getCantonsByCode(cantonCode: string) {    
    this.restService.getSelectedByCode("rcanton", cantonCode)
        .map(results => results["payload"]);
}
```

and subscribe to the Observable in your component.

Comment: when i do console.log this.canton in getCantonsByCode i get data , but in other component when i do console.log i get undefined

Answer (score 0):

If `address.ts` is a parent of `details.ts` then you can use [`@ViewChild`](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/).

Expose your `getCantonsByCode` as a `public` method.

In your `address.html`

`<details #details></details>`

And address.ts

```
@ViewChild('details') details : DetailsComponent
 details.getCantonsByCode(address)
```

Edit: I misunderstood

The reason you are getting undefined is because your method is making an asynchronous call.

This line returns nothing.

```
this.addressDetailForm.addressDetails.viewAttr2 = this.addressDetailForm.getCantonsByCode(address.cantonCode)
```

You will have to change your method to the following.

```
getCantonsByCode(cantonCode: string) : Observable<any>{    
    return this.restService.getSelectedByCode("rcanton", cantonCode)

 }
```

And subscribe to this method wherever you want to pull the value .

```
getCantonsByCode(address.cantonCode).subscribe(results => {
        return this.canton = results["payload"];
    });
```

Comment: Ok what if i move my function in address.ts and i dont need ViewChild, i get again undefined when i do console.log(this.getCantonsByCode(address.cantonCode))

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, you realise the reason you are getting undefined is because your method does not return synchronously? You have no return outside of the subscribe

Comment: When i put it inside subscribe i also get undefined, but in console.log inside subscribe i get data

Comment: @None check my edit, you are misunderstanding the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code.